# How do I use a custom image on a gitlab runner?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecr

I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` and I want the image that the runner uses to be pulled from my ECR. I think this should be easy, I have the runner get credentials from ECR and then pull the image, in a job that runs before the rest:

```
get_image:
  image: node
  stage: get_image
  script: |
    npm install -g aws-cli
    source ./build_scripts/assume-role.sh "${REGION}" "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}" "${CODE_SERVICE_ROLE}"
    aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --no-include-email >> creds.txt



build:
  stage: build
  image: ${IMAGE_URL}
  script: |
    ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "*/*"  
  only:
    - dev
```

However, it tries to pull the docker image before any of the jobs run which means it fails before it can sign in. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't believe this is so complicated! Also one would say this must be a very common setup but after 4 years since this question was asked there were only <400 views?